# Laravel 5.2 Events, Listeners working in local not prod

Tags: php, laravel, events, amazon-ec2, laravel-5

I'm trying to fire an event every time a new user is registered. For this in my **EventServiceProvider** I added

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\UserRegistered' => [
        'App\Listeners\UserRegisteredListener',
    ],
];
```

and ran

```
php artisan event:generate
```

which created me an event **UserRegistered** and a listener **UserRegisteredListener**. In my UserRegistered i have

```
public function __construct(User $user)
{
   $this->user = $user;
}
```

and my UserRegisteredListener i have

```
public function handle(UserRegistered $event)
{
    $user = $event->user;
    $user->cart()->save(new Cart);
    $user->wallet()->save(new Wallet);
}
```

I'm firing the event from my AuthController trait **RegistersUsers**

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($this->create($request->all()));

    Event::fire(new UserRegistered(Auth::user()));

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

> The logic works completely fine on localhost, but when I push it to
>   the prod server which is running an EC2 amazon linux instance the
>   event is not being fired at all.

Answer (score 0):

The event is fired from the **RegistersUsers.php** which is part of the Vendor folder (gitignore). Which is available locally but not on **RegistersUsers.php** of prod.

Moved the event fire to AuthController